# How is the mathematics academic job market outside of North America?

Tags: mathematics

Most of the information online concerns academic positions in math at research-oriented US universities?  In summary, it is extremely competitive.
I'm just wondering, what's the situation at teaching-oriented institutions in the US, and other institutions around the world in Western Europe, Eastern Europe, East Asian countries etc.

Thanks,

Comment: That's an excessively broad question. There are 194 "other" countries...

Comment: But are all university-level math jobs posted on mathjobs.org?  My general question is if the job market is so tough in North America, why not go elsewhere?

Comment: May I ask why this is marked as off-topic? It is a question about the job market.

Comment: You're likely to get better answers to such a question at the [Meta site](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/) than in the comments to a closed question. That said, I think the StackExchange sites use a rather misleading definition for "off-topic". As you say, the academic job market is generally a good topic for the site - but there are [additional restrictions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on what makes a question good and useful or disallowed. Personally, I voted to close because I think the question is too broad. Others considered it a shopping question.

Answer (score 2):

It's very dependent on where you are. I'm from Europe and here it's extremely competitive. In some developing countries though, it's less competitive because there is a great need for university-level teachers, but research is far from the priority in these jobs (according to some of my friends who took them). It all depends on what you're looking for. If you want a research-intensive job in a developed country, expect as much competition as you would in the US: you're not the first one who has the idea to move to get a job.

> But are all university-level math jobs posted on mathjobs.org

No. Outside the US, posting job ads on mathjobs.org is the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: Is it competitive in Western as well as Eastern Europe and the Balkans?

Comment: These questions don't really make sense. Some jobs are competitive, some aren't. You're asking for generalisations of huge areas of the world, when the area of the world isn't the main covariate anyway. A professor level post at Oxford University: hugely competitive. A postdoc down the road at Oxford Brookes... not so much.